# Error al cambiar de ventana con Selenium en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

he estado programando un bot durante bastante tiempo y me iba perfecto pero ahora no se porque me da error cuando intento cambiar de ventana, os dejo aquí el código del cambio de ventana para que le echéis un vistazo:

```py
driver.get("https://temp-mail.org/es/")
    time.sleep(5)
    emailInput = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#mail")
    email = emailInput.get_attribute('value')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get(e6)
    time.sleep(3)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("signup_email").send_keys(email)
    time.sleep(2)
    password_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("signup_password").send_keys(e2)
    password_elem.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    time.sleep(2)
```

Hay más código de cambio de ventanas pero es todo lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Puede que dependiendo de la ejecucion las ventanas sean devueltas en un orden diferente al que esperas en la instruccion `driver.window_handles[1]`

Antes de cambiar de ventana puedes asegurar que el cambio es a la ventana correcta:

```
current_page = driver.current_window_handle
handles = driver.window_handles
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    if handle != main_page:
        driver.switch_to.window(handle)
```

Por supuesto, esto solo es valido con dos ventanas, si tienes mas de dos el control debe ser mayor. Con mas ventanas puedes asegurarte que estas en la correcta preguntando por el titulo de la misma `driver.title`.

Despues de terminar el trabajo en cada ventana siempre podrás volver a la principal, que quedó guardada:

```
driver.switch_to.window(current_page)
```